# Solving Deadlock Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are frequent SELECT, UPDATE, BULK INSERTS happening in database A- Tables and heavy blocking is happening and every time BULK INSERT is chosen as deadlock victim and we are losing some data because of BULK INSERT is failing.

SELECT is blocking BULK INSERT or UPDATE is blocking BULK INSERT every time or vice versa and all these statements (queries) are coming from application. We're not using any stored procedures (unfortunately we cannot use stored procedures)

Database Snapshot is READ Committed, simple recovery model, properly indexed and no fragmentation found. Statistics are up to date, MAXDOP is properly set, optimize for ad hoc workloads=1, AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON,Auto-growth is 500mb for mdf and ldf, tempdb auto growth is 500mb for mdf and ldf ..btw, all databases are sitting on same disk. Memory is 6GB. Total databases size if 60GB. SQL Server 2012 Std edition. PageFile.Sys is 9.8GB. Wait Stats is LCK_M_IX(59%),PAGEIOLATCH_SH(25%)

I was wondering, if there is a way to solve this issue?

1. Is there a way to force the Code coming from application (query plan) to use NO LOCK on SELECT? or any way to Force any query or any login coming xyz application to use NO LOCK?
2. Does Changing ISOLATION LEVEL to READ UNCOMMITTED help?
3. Set deadlock priority LOW?

Comment: This is quite big topic for SO, but have you looked into the details, why does it deadlock? Are the selects reading huge parts of the table or is the whole table getting locked?

Comment: ...what are you expecting? `BULK INSERT` is intended to run alone, or concurrently with other `BULK INSERT` statements. It's definitely not going to play nice with other statements on the same table. Can you `BULK INSERT` in a staging table instead, and then do a regular `INSERT` from there?

Comment: Can you change some of your workload into smaller batches? I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but this could provide some temporary relief, and it would mean you wouldn't have to restart your entire bulk insert.

Comment: JamesZ:the selects reading huge parts of the table --Yes

Comment: Jeroen:Can you BULK INSERT in a staging table instead, and then do a regular INSERT from there-- all Code is called from application and i do not have control over that.

Comment: Arthur:Unfortunately i cannot do anything you mentioned

Comment: Thanks all for looking in to it

Answer (score 1):

The BULK INSERT command has a table lock option which may help your situation. If your bulk insert can acquire an exclusive lock on the table to which you are inserting then other processes will be blocked from using the table until the bulk insert completes. This should allow your bulk insert to avoid the deadlock; however, expect the other competing processes to be blocked and possibly timeout if your bulk insert is long running.

See the excerpt below from MSDN at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

> **TABLOCK**
>
> Specifies that a table-level lock is acquired for the duration of the bulk-import operation. A table can be loaded concurrently by multiple clients if the table has no indexes and TABLOCK is specified. By default, locking behavior is determined by the table option **table lock on bulk load**. Holding a lock for the duration of the bulk-import operation reduces lock contention on the table, in some cases can significantly improve performance. For information about performance considerations, see "Remarks," later in this topic.